# Easy C enum question

Tags: c, enums

I have just started C very recently and I have been asked to answer some coding exercises in which the following piece of code appears:

```
typedef enum {
  false = 0,
  true = 1
} Bool;
```

Could someone please provide a brief and clear explanation to that?

Thanks very much.

Comment: Every time a question like this is asked and one start to answer, he knows that before he had posted his answer there'll be at least other 5 people who already posted their own, hoping like him for an easy hundred points. :P

Comment: Therefore, there are infinite users answering this question. (and infinite of them deleted their own after realizing the duplication so you only see 6 here) :p

Comment: @KennyTM Ah, so that's why SO was so slow earlier this evening! ~>8-(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's really doing two things; you can break it down something like this:

```
enum _bool {
   false = 0,
   true = 1
};
```

And:

```
typedef enum _bool Bool;
```

This code creates a new enumeration type and then uses `typedef` to give it a convenient name.  It would let you use a new 'type' called `Bool` elsewhere in your code, and assign it the values `false` and `true`.  Here's a simple use case:

```
Bool logical_not(Bool in)
{
    if (in == true)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

Comment: Clearly the submitted code does not do that, because _bool does not exist in the original.  I got here because I was trying to find some documentation on "unnamed enum" which is nonsense as far as I'm concerned.  Explaining this needs to be part of the answer.

Comment: Enumerations don't need a label or a typedef; `enum { A, B, C }` is valid code. What are you trying to ask?

Answer (score 4):

It's just a definition of an enum, a type that can assume only a discrete number of values, i.e. the ones enclosed in these brackets. Each of these values is given a name, that you can later use to refer to it. If you only specify the name of the values and not the actual value, the compiler will set them for you in increasing order, starting from zero for the first element.

See the [wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enumerated_type) about enumerated types (and in particular its [C section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enumerated_type#C_and_syntactically_similar_languages)) for more information.

That specific enum defines a boolean type, i.e. a type that can assume only two values: true and false, where false=!true. The boolean values are used very often in programming, for example as flags to indicate if a condition is met, and actually many languages include them as a native type (C++ and C99, for example, do that).

By the way, to define that enum this:

```
enum Bool
{
    false = 0,
    true = 1
};
```

would be enough; however, because of how C was designed to declare a variable of the Bool type with this code you would need to put always the *enum* keyword before Bool:

```
enum Bool myFlag=true;
```

Using the typedef trick, instead, you define an anonymous enum made in that way, and then you provide an alias to it named Bool; in that way you can simply do:

```
Bool myFlag=true;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since C does not have a Boolean data type, your code simulates one by making use of typedef.

You can make use of the new user defined data type as follows:

```
Bool find_key_in_array() {
        Bool found = false; // assume not found.

        // do searching and set found suitably.    

        return found;
}

int main()  {

        Bool result = find_key_in_array();

        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It provides readable literals for true and false. But you could guess that.

How does it work? An enumeration (keyword `enum`) connects a series of tokens with integer values, and the `typedef ... Bool;` makes `Bool` the typename of the enumeration.

On the whole I would discourage this idiom because you might later be tempted to use

```
int flag=false;
// something happens that might change the setting of flag that *doesn't* use the enum
if (flag == true) {
   //...
}
```

and if `flag` got set to 2 this will not do what you expect.

If you use c for long the zero is false everything else is true interpretation will beome second nature.

Answer (score 1):

A enum is an integral type that has a limited number of symbolic values.  This allows you do things like:

```
Bool finish = false;

while (finish != true)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I remember:

This declares an enumeration and then associates a name, **Bool**, to this enumeration (through ***typedef***) .
You can get more information about C enumerations [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/whbyts4t(VS.80).aspx)